# Save Live Audio on Azure Media Server

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure-storage, azure-media-services

We're working on a cloud dictation web application in ASP.NET MVC. We used html5 to record audio. My question is, **can we upload live audio on azure media server while it is been recording on client side**. If yes then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how your HTML app is recording the audio.  Easiest path is to record locally and then upload when you are done recording. If you are using the HTML5 APIs, are you writing a file to local storage first?  If so, what file format? what codec?

It's likely going to differ depending on the browser - Chrome will likely write out a WebM container with Vorbis audio. (I believe there are settings for that as well in the API on Chrome). But the available codec and container will likely be different on Microsoft Edge (MP4 with AAC).

For "Live" Streaming, the only ingest protocol that we currently support is RTMP, and fragmented-MP4, so you would have to find a way to record your live audio and send it to us in one of those protocols from the browser. We don't currently support ingest of WebRTC if that is what you are considering here.

Comment: Are there plans to support webrtc ingest?